# Temporary Tables in mySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, temp-tables

I have started using temp tables in my stored procedures recently. The procedures are created and being dropped explicitly at the end. However I am facing some issues when those procedures are being executed frequently from AWS EC2 instance, the storage usage increased all of a sudden. I have not change anything but this introduction of the temp tables in SP and suspecting if this is the reason for sudden storage usage increase. I am using mySQL 5.7 version. I would like to have your opinion on this if anyone has faced similar situation. Thanks !!

Comment: If theese temptables are compact set them to `ENGINE = Memory`.